# Ban/kick command crashes on use

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I am making a public discord bot, but I am having trouble with one part of my script. My kick/ban commands are made to be done `$ban @user` It has to be done in a ping. Since this is public, I really want to fix this. I don't want one person to mess up and crash it to crash it for all servers. If someone does `$ban user` not in a ping, it crashes the bot. Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("$kick")) {
    if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "MODS"))
      return;
    // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
    var member = message.mentions.members.first();
    // Kick
    member.kick().then((member) => {
      // Successmessage
      message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
    }).catch(() => {
      // Failmessage
      message.channel.send("Access Denied");
    });
  }
});
```

I don't want my bot to keep crashing to ruin the use for others, can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashed when you have no mention because you did not catch this use case.

Adding a simple catch, with a return for example, should work for you :

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("$kick")) {
        if(!message.member.roles.find("name", "MODS"))
            return;
        // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
        var member= message.mentions.members.first();

        // No mentions catch
        if (member === undefined) return;

        // Kick
        member.kick().then((member) => {
            // Successmessage
            message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
             // Failmessage
            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening when you type `$ban user` (Which isn't a mention), and later when you assign  `var member = message.mentions.members.first();` it gives you null (Because no one was mentioned). Try to make sure that `message.mentions.members` isn't empty.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you, both your answers helped!